# Xdebug - Debug adapter process has terminated unexpectedly

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I am using Visual Studio Code:

[image]

I have also installed the PHP Debug Extension Version 1.12.1. My PHP Version is:

```
>php --version
PHP 7.1.8 (cli) (built: Aug  1 2017 21:10:46) ( ZTS MSVC14 (Visual C++ 2015) x86 )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.5.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2017, by Derick Rethans
```

I have configured xdebug following the instructions on the `PHP Debug` plugin.

My settings inside my `php.ini` look like the following:

```
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.5.5-7.1-vc14.dll"

[XDebug]
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.idekey = "whatever"
```

When running `phpinfo();` my xdebug shows correctly:

[image]

My `launch.json` file looks the following:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9000
        }
    ]
}
```

However, when running the configuration I get:

[image]

The error log looks like the following:

```
messageService.ts:126 Debug adapter process has terminated unexpectedly
e.doShow    @   messageService.ts:126
e.show  @   messageService.ts:105
_.onServerExit  @   rawDebugSession.ts:535
(anonymous) @   rawDebugSession.ts:449
emitTwo @   events.js:111
emit    @   events.js:194
__dirname.ChildProcess._handle.onexit   @   internal/child_process.js:215
```

Any suggestions what might be wrong with debugging?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: What are your xdebug.ini settings?

Comment: @Farkie Thx for your answer! I do not have a `xdebug.ini` file. However, I updated my answer with the `xdebug` settings in my `php.ini` file.

Answer (score 0):

Your `vscode` config looks fine *(at least for pure-Windows PHP debugging)*. Your `php.ini` Xdebug config is unnecessarily filled with unimportant stuff *(at least for debugging)*.

Get rid of the whole thing and **try this** minimal `xdebug` config:

```
[XDebug]
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 0
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.idekey = "whatever"
```

Then *(if you use **Chrome**)* you can use this extension to manage enabling/disabling debug sessions: [Xdebug helper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xdebug-helper/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc)

Note: *This is for debugging via browser - **Chrome**. I guess some equivalent plugin should exist for Firefox, but I haven't tried that. If you use Linux or [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl) on Windows 10, you can enable debugging session by setting the proper environment variable like `export XDEBUG_CONFIG="idekey=whatever"` in Linux terminal. I suppose some equivalent exists with pure Windows command-line, but I haven't tried that, either.*

Comment: Thx you for your answer! I configured my php.ini file as described. However, I still get the same error. I am trying to debug a laravel command, so running xdebug locally is somehow needed...

Comment: That's too bad :/ I would definitely recommend *(if you have Windows 10)* installing WSL and running *Apache*, *PHP*, *DB*, etc. under that. It's more developer and config friendly (and even slightly faster) that on pure Windows. If that's not something you want to try, I would inspect if there's any clue in `vscode`'s devtools' console, I would inspect if there's anything in PHP's `error.log` file and I would try [putting `"log": true`](https://github.com/felixfbecker/vscode-php-debug) in `vscode`'s *"Listen for XDebug"* debug config and seeing if any clue appears there.